# Using .bib files for bibliographies

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, journal-publishing, journal

When using references in my document, I'm used to having a central `.bib` file from which I pull all my references (using `\bibliography{path/to/bibfile}`) and then let the journal's `.bst` file do the formatting. When I'm ready to send it to the publishers, I'll manually paste in the contents of the `.bbl` file, which is now also styled correctly.

This has served me well so far. Now, one journal's [style files](http://www.blackwellpublishing.com/pdf/gji-latex.zip) forces bibliographies to be entered only between `\begin{thebibliography}...\end{...}`. If I do what I have been doing previously, I get the error:

```
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item
```

and this is the output in the `.bbl` file:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{0}
\expandafter\ifx\csname natexlab\endcsname\relax\def\natexlab#1{#1}\fi

\end{thebibliography}
```

What's going on here? Is there some option I can avail of to get back to my old behavior?

---

Here's an MWE (or non-MWE):

#### 1: .tex file

```
\documentclass{gji}
\begin{document}
    Lorem Ipsum \cite{test}
    \bibliographystyle{gji}
    \bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

#### 2: .bib file

```
@article{test,
    author  = {F. Bar},
    title   = {Lorem Ipsum},
    journal = {J. Dolor Sit Am.},
    volume  = {1},
    pages   = {1--10},
    year    = {2012},
}
```

Use the `.cls` and `.bst` files from the link above. My standard compilation routine is `pdflatex-bibtex-pdflatex-pdflatex`

Comment: The output in the .bbl file is only this much? There are no bibitem entries?!

Comment: @NobleP.Abraham Yes, that's part of the problem...

Comment: See this from the file *gji_extraguide.pdf* in the linked zip. `For the above examples to function properly, either the gji bibliography style must be used with BibTeX, or the thebibliography environment must be formatted accordingly`

Comment: @NobleP.Abraham I've added a minimal example

Comment: your MWE compiles with no problem for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `\cite` command to add references.

```
\documentclass{gji} 
\begin{document}
Lorem Ipsum \cite{test}
\bibliographystyle{gji}
\bibliography{test} 
\end{document}
```

In any method of compilation i.e. `latex-bibtex-latex-latex-dvips-ps2pdf` or `pdflatex-bibtex-pdflatex-pdflatex` the output is produced.

The resulting `.bbl` file is here

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\expandafter\ifx\csname natexlab\endcsname\relax\def\natexlab#1{#1}\fi

\bibitem[Bar(2012)]{test}
Bar, F., 2012.
\newblock Lorem ipsum, {\it J. Dolor Sit Am.\/}, {\bf 1}, 1--10.

\end{thebibliography}
```

If desired output is not obtained, try deleting `.log`,`.blg`,`.aux`,`.bbl` files before compiling again.

Comment: uhh... that's in my MWE. This is the same thing.

Comment: Oh you edited it. Then it should be working, now

Comment: This is the example that doesn't work and gives the error... does it compile for you?

Comment: Yes I got it working. will post the .bbl

Comment: it's strange that the example compiles on your machine, but not mine... any ideas on how to debug/where to look for sources of error?

Comment: See updated route to compile

Comment: No, still won't compile. I don't think the difference between latex and pdflatex matters here for this minimal example. This is crazy!

Comment: @ksr I tried the minimal example in your question with the linked gji.cls and gji.bst and it worked fine. Your empty .bbl looks as if bibtex failed for some reason, so you should check the log-file of bibtex (.blg).

Comment: Ok, I'm accepting this because 2 users have confirmed it works, so the issue must be on my end... I'll poke at it further. Thanks to both for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem in IEEE Transaction's paper. I was having the following lines:

```
\bibliography{IEEEabrv}
\bibliography{Review_PAMI}
```

The first line is IEEE database for abbreviations and second contain my references. In my case first line was creating problem. Once I commented the first line it worked for me.